# Python Prime Numbers Looping

Tags: python

I am trying to find the prime numbers in a list. I wrote the code below. My code returns

```
not prime
prime
prime
prime
prime
prime
prime
prime
```

I think the problem is with the second loop, it is not iterating past 2 but i couldn't figure out why. Any reason why it is doing it?

```
check_prime = [26, 39, 51, 53, 57, 79, 85]


for i in check_prime:
    for m in range(2,i):
        if i%(m)!=0:
            print("prime")
            break
        else:
            i%(m)==0
            print("not prime")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should print `prime` after you check all of the *divisors* and you don't find any divisor for a given number.

So, I recommend to write a *function* which checks if a *number* is `prime` or `not`.

```
check_prime = [26, 39, 51, 53, 57, 79, 85]

def check_if_prime(nr):
    for m in range(2,nr):
        if nr%(m) == 0:
           return False
    return True
 for i in check_prime:
    print('prime' if check_if_prime(i) else 'not prime')
```

Output

```
not prime
not prime
not prime
prime
not prime
prime
not prime
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to check if i%m != 0 for **any** i (and that's what you're doing now), but for **all** i's in range(2,i). And the best way to do it is to use a generator and function all():

```
check_prime = [26, 39, 51, 53, 57, 79, 85]
for i in check_prime:
    if all(i % m != 0 for m in range(2,i)):
        print("prime")
    else:
        print("not prime")
```

Comment: Closing bracket. Too small for an edit, too much for the interpreter ... `if all(i % m != 0 for m in range(2,i)):`

Answer (score 0):

```
l=[26,39,51,53,57,79,85]

l1=[]
for i in range(len(l)):
    for j in range(2,(l[i]//2)+1):
        if l[i]%j==0:
            c=0
            break
        else:
            c=1
    if c==1:
        print("prime")
    else:
        print("not prime")
```